Page Scaling Issue After Rotating Device, Entering Fullscreen, and Exiting Fullscreen on Mobile Browsers
I'm experiencing an issue where the page scale increases slightly after performing the following sequence of actions on a Android mobile device (i am using Chrome):

Access a rottentomatoes.com in portrait mode.
Rotate the device to landscape mode.
Enter then exit fullscreen mode by open a trailer video then touch "Fullscreen" button
or using JavaScript in Chrome Devtool Console (document.body.requestFullscreen() then document.exitFullscreen()).
Rotate the device back to portrait mode.


After this sequence, the page appears slightly scaled up, even though the viewport meta tag is set to width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0.
I suspect this is related to how the browser handles viewport scaling during fullscreen mode and orientation changes. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, I'm curious about the cause and knowledge behind this phenomenon. Looking forward to your answer. Thank you all.

I can reproduce this problem on Windows 11 in Chrome using the device toolbar. I can't reproduce it in Firefox. That seems to suggest it is a browser (engine) problem. Are you actually having the same problem on your website? You didn't say that, which could make this question off-topic. Stack Overflow is for questions developers have with regard to their own work.

I see a different phenomenon on Firefox from Chrome, the page scale is increase as soon as the orientation is landscape then the scale is not increase when fullscreen. Since Firefox and Chrome has different rendering engine, i think its just a different rather than a problem. I am a quite newbie and just have a question...

In addition, i see that when i change the meta viewport tag from
"initial-scale=1" to "minimum-scale=1" the phenomenon not happens. Though i am still wonder about base on what element or why its scale to that level?

javascript:(function () {var script=document.createElement('script');script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda";document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
